# Join attributes by field value doesn't work in the graphical modeler, but works from processing toolbox

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have been trying to join two fields with id's together. Most of the id's are the same, but some are in one field and not in the other, and the otherway around. I need to join the two fields to see if the geometry of the polygons are different from eachother.

This is what the attribute tables look like. Both BAGid fields are a string field with a length of 15 characters:[image]

If I try to join them by the 'BAGid' field value from the processing toolbox, it works fine. But when I try it in the graphical modeler, I get an error message.
This is my input from the graphical modeler:
[image]

This is the error message I receive when trying to run the algorithm.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks around the field names you hand to the model.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much for helping!